Accent-color, стилизовать вторую половину ползунка


input[type="range"] {
   accent-color : red;
}
<input type="range">



Замучался с этим. Как убрать бордюр с трека и вторую половину ползунка сделать скажем желтым?

https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-custom-css-range-slider-javascript-upgrades/
